# Punishment for marital rape?

Tags: manu-smriti

I had read a story where a king asked his menstruating wife to have an intercourse with him and she refused; but since he kept on insisting, his punishment would be that he gets casted to hell
This is most probably from Manusmriti but I'm unsure;

Can anyone tell me where this story is from?

Comment: Approaching a wife in her season is not same as marital rape. Are you sure the punishment was for marital rape and not the other?

Comment: I never heard such story, If anyone found this please post link here. In general, 10 years is the maximum sentence for marital rape. In order to prosecute, the married victim must report the rape within 30 days, even if they are living separately from their spouse.